# VueJS - passing slots and scoped slots down to the component in child template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to figure out a way how to pass slots/scoped slots down from a parent component to a child component. Let me explain...

I've created a data table component using bootstrap-vue **b-table** component. A very simplified code would be something like this:

**DataTable.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <page-selector/>
        <b-table></b-table>
        <pager/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I accept a list of fields definition and api endpoint as a prop, pass it down to **b-table**, and everything is working fine. For example component to render all the users in the DataTable:

**UsersTable.vue:**

```
<template>
     <data-table :fields="fields" :url="url"/>
</template>
```

The problem I'm facing is following:

bootstrap-vue component **b-table** uses multiple slots. For example a slot to change a table caption (`<template slot="table-caption">This is a table caption.</template>`), or scoped slots to format fields in the table, or to allow html characters (`<span slot="email" slot-scope="data" v-html="data.value"></span>`).

How am I able to pass both slots and scoped slots from UsersTable component to DataTable component so they are available as slots in the **b-table** component? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am not thinking straight right now but it seems to me that you can just add the same named slots in your `DataTable.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <page-selector/>
        <b-table>
            <template slot="table-caption"><slot name="table-caption"></slot></template>
            ....
        </b-table>
        <pager/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course that did the trick, it's looks so obvious to me now, #facepalm. What would be a similar approach for scoped slots? The issue is that the slot name is dynamic and only known to UsersTable, as it contains the name of a specific field from :fields.

Comment: So after searching a bit it looks to me it might not be that easy. I'm able to access this.$scopedSlots in DataTable component, but can't find a way how to bind it to scopedSlots of b-table.

Comment: Looks like [this PR](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/7765) would be a solution...